# Create a git repository from commits of a previous one

Tags: git, github

I was part of a project that involved creating a redmine plugin with lot of features.

Now I want to take some of the features and turn them into individual plugins. For that I will create one separate git repository for each.

In that git repository I would like to have the intact history from the original git repository with only the files related to that feature.

Should I had the older repository as a remote and go through every commit manually, finding the ones that interest me, and committing them to the new repository?

Or is there another (more practical) way to do it?

The workflow on the old git repository was:

- There was only the master branch;
- Every time a milestone was completed
  it was committed and pushed to the
  remote;

Comment: This is going to be difficult to give more than abstract help with since your git habits with the old repository will dictate what tools we have to pull the features out. You should also consider the option of starting new repositories using your modified code, leaving the old history behind.

Comment: I updated the question with a simple workflow of the old repository. If the choice was going through every commit and see what were the ones I want or leave the old history behind, I would go manually through every commit. Was just wondering if there's a more practical way of doing it

Comment: Are the individual plugins you're trying to create separated into different subdirectories in your original repository? (really easy) Separate files? (not too bad) All tangled up with each other? (not gonna happen)

Comment: Except for the routes file every feature has different files.

Comment: You probably want to look for examples of filter-branch with tree filters, then. For each plugin, you can create a clone of the repo, then filter the history to keep only the files for that plugin. That routes file, whatever it is, will have to stay with all of them, then maybe you can just top each repository with a single commit doing whatever cleanup is necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [git-filter-branch(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) which is Git's Swiss-army knife for automated rewriting of history and it certainly allows you to keep all commits touching a defined set of files (and drop everything else).

How to use it in detail, depends on your actual repository. If, for example, all the files you want to keep are already neatly contained in a subdirectory (say, `foobar`), then the following would be sufficient:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foobar --prune-empty -- --all
```

As an alternative, you could use the following to remove all files but the ones you want to keep from your repository:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f filename1 pattern2.*' --prune-empty -- --all
```

Comment: It's a rails project so the files are spread around a lot of folders. So if I understood correctly this will go to every commit and remove the files that I consider are not important? if so, won't I have blank commits? or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: @nunopolonia: The `--prune-empty` option tells git to leave out commits that wouldn't do anything once the tree filter has been applied. But don't take my word for it - clone your repo and give this a shot!

Comment: Already cloned it and starting to play with it. Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 4):

Rather than rewriting history to extract just the files you're interested in, you could keep the original history — which provides the context for all the changes — and add a new commit which just deletes all the files you *aren't* interested in.

Clone the original repository, then make a branch for each plugin, and on each branch, delete anything that isn't relevant to that plugin.  That way, all your plugins have history that traces back to their common origins.

Comment: The original plugin is something that I want to forget. I would like to have a repository for each plugin as if they were always developed separately.